# Visual Studio - Custom document tab bar grouping

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

Does anybody know how the Visual Studio editor can be customized to group certain open documents together. It's almost like the "Document Well 2010 Plus" extension (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/10/document-well-2010-plus.aspx). We don't want to group them by project, but on another custom way. I searched in the "editor extension points" document, but could not find something useful.

Comment: What custom way? Tab coloring supports [regular expressions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/10/document-well-2010-plus.aspx#coloringtabs)

Comment: try Productivity Power Tools (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef for vs2010). You can pin documents to group them and order them

Comment: My question was how that we can do it in our own extension. We open a main code file, but for each file we have also some detail views. Now I want that the detail views are always grouped with the main view. For example: Main1-Detail1-Detail2-Main2-Detail2-Detail2. And not: Main1-Main1-Detail1-Detail1-Detail2-Detail2.

Comment: did you find out how to modify the document well yet? I'm currently looking into that myself.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of the following ways that may help you:

- Use [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) - this groups and colours tabs based on project
- Tear off the tabs you want to keep together into a new window
- If you want them really separate - open a new instance of Visual Studio!
- You could also try [Tabs Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/EBF6137E-AA2D-4DC9-860A-F04168F11CD7), however, I have tried it and didn't really like it that much, though may suit your needs.

Comment: But how can I create the tabs in my own extension? I DONT want to install another extension for that. How do other extensions implement this? Which classes of the SDK are involved?

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2017, [Productivity Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017) has been broken up into a bunch of extensions, so now the one people would want for this question is [Custom Document Well](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.CustomDocumentWell)

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in Visual Studio 2019